# Using a for loop to store ggplot2 objects in a list

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to visualize the dataset listed here using the packages from the tidyverse collection:
https://www.kaggle.com/ruslankl/mice-protein-expression
The dataset contains 80+ variables. I would like to make 77 plots in total, each with the explanatory variable, Genotype, plotted against each of 77 other variables of interest from the dataset. I attempted to do this with a for loop containing the ggplot function that would iterate over all 77 columns and store each resulting plot in a list:

```
DCN_byclass = group_by(Data_Cortex_Nuclear, class, Genotype) %>%
  select(-Behavior, -Treatment, -MouseID) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
classes = c('c-CS-s','c-CS-m','c-SC-s','c-SC-m','t-CS-s','t-CS-m','t-SC-s','t-SC-m')
desc = c('control mice, stimulated to learn, injected with saline',
         'control mice, stimulated to learn, injected with memantine',
         'control mice, not stimulated to learn, injected with saline',
         'control mice, not stimulated to learn, injected with memantine',
         'trisomy mice, stimulated to learn, injected with saline',
         'trisomy mice, stimulated to learn, injected with memantine',
         'trisomy mice, not stimulated to learn, injected with saline',
         'trisomy mice, not stimulated to learn, injected with memantine')
class_desc = tibble(class = classes, description = desc)
DCN_byclass = left_join(DCN_byclass, class_desc, by = 'class')
DCN_byclass = select(DCN_byclass, class, description, Genotype, everything())
plots = list()
for (i in 1:77) {
plots[i] =
ggplot(DCN_byclass, mapping = aes(Genotype, DCN_byclass[,(i+3)], fill = class)) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge')
}
```

However, the loop returns 50 instances of this warning:

```
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

When I attempt to access a plot from the list by indexing it, a tibble rather than a plot is returned:

```
> plots[1]
[[1]]
# A tibble: 8 x 81
# Groups:   class [8]
  class description Genotype DYRK1A_N ITSN1_N BDNF_N
  <chr> <chr>       <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 c-CS~ control mi~ Control     0.480   0.653  0.339
2 c-CS~ control mi~ Control     0.597   0.772  0.342
3 c-SC~ control mi~ Control     0.273   0.436  0.291
4 c-SC~ control mi~ Control     0.275   0.449  0.313
5 t-CS~ trisomy mi~ Ts65Dn      0.619   0.797  0.313
6 t-CS~ trisomy mi~ Ts65Dn      0.526   0.760  0.305
7 t-SC~ trisomy mi~ Ts65Dn      0.330   0.567  0.321
8 t-SC~ trisomy mi~ Ts65Dn      0.337   0.549  0.326
# ... with 75 more variables: NR1_N <dbl>, NR2A_N <dbl>,
```

Is there a way of rewriting this loop that'll allow it to return the desired plots?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `plots[[i]]` instead of `plots[i]`.
Reason for this is that `[[` returns the value of an element in the list, whereas `[` returns a new list, see [subsetting](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html).
`plots[[i]]` allows to store a plot object at index i in list `plots` : this is what you intend do.
Using `plots[i]` stores the first element of the plot object (ie its data) in the first element of the `plots` list, and issues a warning because a ggplot object is a list composed of 9 elements (`data`,`layers`,`scales`,...) and only the first one could be assigned.

```r
library(ggplot2)
plots <- list()
for (i in 1:2) {
  plots[i] =
    ggplot(mtcars)+geom_point(aes(x=cyl,y=hp))
}
#> Warning in plots[i] <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x = cyl, y = hp)): 
#> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

#> Warning in plots[i] <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x = cyl, y = hp)): 
#> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
plots[1]
#> [[1]]
#>                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> ...

for (i in 1:2) {
  plots[[i]] =
    ggplot(mtcars)+geom_point(aes(x=cyl,y=hp))
}
plots[[1]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It seems that using plots[[i]] does allow the for loop to return a list with ggplot objects. However, when I try to access one of these plots, say with plots[[1]], I get the following message: "Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. Defaulting to continuous."

Comment: This looks like a warning you would also get with the plot outside the loop.